# Open settings if it's app's first run

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uistoryboard

I'm developing an iPhone application with latest `SDK` and `XCode`.

I'm using storyboarding and I don't know how to open a view when user runs the app at first time.

I will check if there is user `preferences` saved, and, if there isn't, I will open settings view:

```
prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if ([prefs stringForKey:APP_LANGUAGE_KEY] == nil)
{
    // Open SettingsViewController;
}
else
{
    // Continue usually.
}
```

This is my storyboard:
[image]

**How can I do it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got it right. Just make sure you set a key at the first launch.

```
NSString *key = @"AppWasLaunchedInThePast";
BOOL firstLaunch = ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];
if (firstLaunch) {
    // First launch. Open settings.
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"FileName" bundle:nil];
    NSString *anID = @"SettingsViewController"; // or whatever you set in IB.
    SettingsViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:anID];
    // push vc to your navigation controller, or present it modally here.
} else {
    // Not first launch.
}
// Make sure we remember that the app was launched:
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:key];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to open settings view controller or continue usually.

Comment: I don't think you're answering the question. I believe he's asking how to open the Setting's VC, he's already detecting the first launch correctly.

Comment: He wants to know how to open the view controller

Comment: Just a note: At the first time I would recommend to use registerDefaults: instead of setBool:forKey: .

Comment: If your problem is about displaying a view controller, why do you ask about "first start". That has nothing to do with it. Use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` to get a specific view controller from a storyboard. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

To open the view use

```
SettingsViewController *settingsView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingsViewController"];
```

Comment: @VansFannel put that code inside your if statement were you have //Open settingsviewcontroller

Comment: Oh, sorry. I haven't explained well. I am asking about if I need to put that code on AppDelegate, MenuViewController or in another class.

Comment: @VansFannel you can place it in MenuViewController

Answer (score 0):

You can just display a modal view on first launch from your apps initial view controller.

Place your first start check in the viewDidAppear of your initial view controller and call:

```
    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```